# Changing Stack's storage directory on Windows

Tags: haskell-stack

On Windows, Stack uses `%AppData/stack` as its storage directory by default. Is there a way to change that? I've only managed to move executables (by setting `local-bin-path` in the global `config.yaml` file), but I'd like all GHC versions, compiled packages, etc. to be stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently supported, but it should be fairly straightforward to add.  I've added a ticket for it here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2067

The relevant code is here https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/6f7871b893de2792ad9b9a02d934dfa72f8d9090/src/Stack/Config.hs#L266

Comment: This is now supported and can be used by adding `local-programs-path: <path>` to `config.yaml`.