# Completely avoid use of %APPDATA% when installing Haskell Stack on Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell

Trying to install Haskell / ghci for the first time, though I intend to try it under a MSYS2 `bash` shell on Windows 10.

Anyways, I was somewhat surprised to experience that it is very difficult to specify a custom location for everything Haskell related.

So, https://www.haskell.org/ghc/ recommends using "ghcup or Stack" to install, and https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ says "On 64-bit Windows, the easiest way to install Stack directly (rather than use GHCup) is to download and install the [Windows installer](https://get.haskellstack.org/stable/windows-x86_64-installer.exe)." - so I decided to go with Stack, and got `stack-2.13.1-windows-x86_64-installer.exe`.

Upon running the installer, it wanted to use `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\local\bin` to install, but for one I don't really like digging in AppData (and I also might run out of space on C:, so might have to choose a different drive for this install) - so to begin with, I replaced the installation path to `C:\HaskellStack`, and let the installer finish.

Note that while the installer does indeed change the Windows 10 System/Advanced/Environment Variables/User variables for [USER]: Path, somehow that did not propagate to my existing MSYS2 `bash` shell, and since I did not want to reboot the PC, below I'm using a full path to call `stack.exe`.

I kind of thought that I'd get a full install (which includes `ghc` and whatever else is needed), but no - after the installer finishes, at start, there are only two files in the installation directory:

```
$ ls /c/HaskellStack/
stack.exe*  uninstall-stack.exe*
```

OK, so I thought, I'd try running `ghci` first - and I got this:

```
$ /c/HaskellStack/stack.exe ghci
Writing the configuration file for the implicit global project to:
C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml. Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field
there.
Using the latest snapshot lts-22.5.
...
```

Oh, wait - NO, I do not want anything to do with `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData` - why is it there? So, I found [Changing Stack's storage directory on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831051/changing-stacks-storage-directory-on-windows) and from there, [Option for location of programs installed by setup · Issue #2067 · commercialhaskell/stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2067)

Ok, so did a full uninstall (of "Haskell Stack" under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features), then reinstalled stack installer; and this time I started with:

```
$ /c/HaskellStack/stack.exe --stack-root
The option `--stack-root` expects an argument.

$ /c/HaskellStack/stack.exe path --stack-root
Writing the configuration file for the implicit global project to:
C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml. Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field
there.
Using the latest snapshot lts-22.5.
msys2-20230526: download has begun^C
```

Oh, damn it - so even if I just want to print out the "stack-root" path, `stack` *still* starts with a download into `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData`; ughh, how irritating.

Ok, so did a full uninstall (of "Haskell Stack" under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features), then reinstalled stack installer; and this time I started with:

```
$ /c/HaskellStack/stack.exe --stack-root 'C:\HaskellStack'
Missing: COMMAND|FILE
```

Right, so I cannot "just" set "stack-root" path in this way...

So finally I decided to set STACK_ROOT as a (temporary) environment variable, and then call `path --stack-root` to simply print out the "stack-root" path; this time I wasn't really surprised that this started up a download:

```
$ STACK_ROOT='C:\HaskellStack' /c/HaskellStack/stack.exe path --stack-root
Writing the configuration file for the implicit global project to: C:\HaskellStack\global-project\stack.yaml. Note: You can
change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
Using the latest snapshot lts-22.5.
Downloaded msys2-20230526.
Downloaded 7z.dll.
Downloaded 7z.exe.
Decompressing msys2-20230526.tar.xz...

7-Zip 22.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2022 Igor Pavlov : 2022-07-15

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 80821956 bytes (78 MiB)

Extracting archive: C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20230526.tar.xz
...
```

AAAARGH !!!!! ... so, even if it started fine, still bloody downloads end up in `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData`.

So, how can I install and setup Haskell `stack` on Windows 10, so it NEVER does ANYTHING in `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData`, not downloading, not installing there, and it does not even ever create the `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Programs\stack` directory?

Comment: I'm not a stack expert, but probably downloading to somewhere other than a STACK_ROOT subdirectory is a bug, and I'd report it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Given the [Stack root contents](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/stack_root/#contents) don’t include the tools:

> The Stack root contains snapshot packages; Stack's global YAML configuration file (`config.yaml`); and Stack's `global-projects` directory. The default location of tools such as GHC and MSYS2 is outside of the Stack root.

And that you can override “the default location of tools” by setting the [local programs path](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#local-programs-path):

> Default: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\stack`, if the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` environment variable exists. Otherwise, the `programs` directory in the Stack root.

> The MSYS2 tool is also installed in the Stack `programs` directory.

I guess here is your problem: the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` setting is overriding the `STACK_ROOT` setting. You could unset `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, but I think you should instead unset `STACK_ROOT` and set `STACK_XDG`:

> Stack can be configured to follow the XDG Base Directory Specification if the environment variable `STACK_XDG` is set to any non-empty value. However, Stack will ignore that configuration if the Stack root location has been set on the command line or the `STACK_ROOT` environment variable exists.

Then you can set the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) environment variables `XDG_DATA_HOME` and `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, or by default Stack will use a subdirectory of `%APPDIR%`.

> The Stack root is `%XDG_DATA_HOME%/stack`. If the `XDG_DATA_HOME` environment variable does not exist, the default is […] `%APPDIR%\stack` on Windows.

> The location of `config.yaml` is `%XDG_CONFIG_HOME%/stack`. If the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable does not exist, the default is […] `%APPDIR%\stack` on Windows.

Aside, the XDG spec is a great thing to follow if you’re writing a command-line tool, since it clarifies a lot of these configuration issues.

If Stack doesn’t respect these settings, it’s probably a bug that you should report. It’s also possible to just use Cabal without Stack.

[GHCup also supports XDG](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/guide/#xdg-support) if `GHCUP_USE_XDG_DIRS` is set.